# Efficient way to retrieve all values from a column that start with other values from the same column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

For the sake of simplicity, suppose you have a table with numbers like:

```
| number |
----------
|123     |
|1234    |
|12345   |
|123456  |
|111     |
|1111    |
|2       |
|700     |
```

What would be an efficient way of retrieving the shortest numbers (call them *roots* or whatever) and all values *derived* from them, eg:

```
| root   | derivatives         |
--------------------------------
| 123    | 1234, 12345, 123456 |
| 111    | 1111                |
```

Numbers `2` & `700` are excluded from the list because they're *unique*, and thus have no derivatives.

An output as the above would be ideal, but since it's probably difficult to achieve, the next best thing would be something like below, which I can then post-process:

```
| root   | derivative |
-----------------------
| 123    | 1234       |
| 123    | 12345      |
| 123    | 123456     |
| 111    | 1111       |
```

My *naive* initial attempt to at least identify *roots* (see below) has been running for 4h now with a dataset of ~500k items, but the real one I'd have to inspect consists of millions.

```
select number
from numbers n1
where exists(
              select number
              from numbers n2
              where n2.number <> n1.number
                and n2.number like n1.number || '_%'
          );
```

Comment: Do you have an index on the `number` column? Either a B-Tree index with `varchar_pattern_ops` or maybe even a trigram index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the column in question is a PK, but other than that it does not have any special indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if `number` is an `integer` or `bigint`:

```
select min(a.number) as root, b.number as derivative
  from nums a
       cross join lateral generate_series(1, 18) as gs(power)
       join nums b 
         on b.number / (10^gs.power)::bigint = a.number
 group by b.number
 order by root, derivative;
```

**EDIT:  I moved a non-working query to the bottom.  It fails for reasons outlined by @Morfic in the comments.**

We can do a similar and simpler join using `like` for character types:

```
select min(a.number) as root, b.number as derivative
  from numchar a
       join numchar b on b.number like a.number||'%'
        and b.number != a.number
 group by b.number
 order by root, derivative;
```

Updated [fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=be9f1f0e0fcc3e42672c85eac2e36515)

**Faulty Solution Follows**

If number is a character type, then try this:

```
with groupings as (
  select number, 
         case
           when number like (lag(number) over (order by number))||'%' then 0
           else 1
         end as newgroup
    from numchar
), groupnums as (
  select number, sum(newgroup) over (order by number) as groupnum
    from groupings
), matches as (
  select min(number) over (partition by groupnum) as root,
         number as derivative
    from groupnums
)
select *
  from matches
 where root != derivative;
```

There should be only a single sort on `groupnum` in this execution since the column is your table's primary key.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e4d2caf207fb33707833a650ec9d8cb0)*

Comment: Thanks, that partially worked. You guessed right, the number column is varchar. By partially I mean that if I add for example a `1235` value in there, it doesn't show up in the results,  but I'm still trying to understand how the query works, so if you have the time and feel like it, I'd appreciate a brief description of your train of thought when you came up with this.

Comment: I thin I got it, and the problem with the varchar solution: we tag each number with a group identifier by iterating through the numbers, and if the `current number` is like `previous%` (with `lag()`)  we're in the same group (0), otherwise it's a new group (1). Then we pick the shortest number from each group (aka root) and each number from that group. Finally, excluding groups with 1 entry only (meaning there are no derivatives, just the root), we're left with what we need. Nice! Unfortunately, `lag` doesn't work if we have `123`, `1234`, `1235`

Comment: Luckily I actually do have numbers to analyze, so I believe I can still use the first solution with `number::bigint`, but it would be interesting to see if the second solution would be possible, say in case you had words such as `cat`, `catalogue`, `caterpillar`. Either way, much obliged!

Comment: @Morfic I am sorry that my solution was wrong.  I started down the path of trying to identify roots without doing a join, and I cannot think of a way to do it without recursion.  I added a solution using like comparisons similar to the numeric solution.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, easily missable as the OP dataset was "_faulty_". Yeah, that was also my initial attempt but it's very slow. Seems casting/converting to numbers, doing division by several orders of 10 and comparing for equality is WAY faster than `like`. Well, maybe someone else will come up with something :-)