# Querying all ids which have specific left-most digits

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have queried specific ids from a table. Now I want to find all the ids in the same table that would be postfixes for the ids I initially fetched. For example

If I fetch 1, 2, 3, 4
I want to get all the ids

```
| 1 | 10, 12, 13, 11, 111, 100, 1000.... |
| 2 | 20, 222, 23, 21, 20, 2999, 2000....|
```

and so on. I would be able to easily handle this via code but Can't seem to figure out how to proceed with Postgres, Would I have to cast the entire column as a String to make this work?

Comment: Please see the numeric solution at the top of this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72748915/13808319

Comment: Are negative values possible in the data. If present what do you done with them?

Comment: No negative values aren't possible since the IDs are auto-incremented

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: mis-interpreted the example for the sole situation (single digit prefixes).

For this to work with any length of prefix, the where condition would be as follows:

```
WHERE CAST( ID/POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG(ID)) ) * POWER(10,FLOOR(LOG(selectedID))) AS integer) = selectedID
```

**The following only works for 1 digit prefixes:**

If the IDs have a small (~10) digit maximum and if they're stored as integers, you could divide by 10 multiple times in the where clause:

```
... 
WHERE ID/10 = selectedID
OR ID/100 = selectedID 
OR ID/1000 = selectedID
OR....
```

etc.

Alternatively, using LOG, CAST, FLOOR, and POWER, if the IDs can be very long:

```
WHERE CAST( ID / POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG(id))) AS integer) = selectedID
```

replacing `= selectedID` with `IN (list of IDs)` as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This was too fun to pass up.

If you have search ids with multiple digits, you can use `log()` to figure out what the divisor should be:

```
with query as (
  select generate_series(1, 2, 1) as search_id
  union all
  select 20
)
select q.search_id, array_agg(t.id) as matches
  from query q
       left join my_table t
         on floor(log(t.id)) > floor(log(q.search_id))
        and floor(t.id / 10^(floor(log(t.id)) - floor(log(q.search_id)))) = q.search_id
 group by q.search_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=00fe7b38f1e1b5b7b5fd0702de985083)*